# Heroku shows error page after CRUD operations, but operations are actually going through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a site live on heroku with a model Journey. When I create a new Journey model, it will create and redirect to to "....com/journeys", but it will be a 404 "We're Sorry" page. If I try to refresh the page, it will resubmit the form again, creating another of the same model entity, but will still redirect to the we're sorry page.

However, if I simply load up another instance of the website and proceed to the .com/journeys extension, the Journeys are indeed listed in the index. Looking at my database from `heroku run rails console`, it also appears that the Journey models are indeed saved.

I pulled up heroku logs to see what might be happening, and I think I've narrowed down the part that might be causing problems

```
2015-07-13T00:48:07.811859+00:00 app[web.1]:   SQL (2.0ms)  INSERT INTO "journeys" ("title", "description", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) ...... 
2015-07-13T00:48:07.816912+00:00 app[web.1]:   Journey Store (2.2ms)  {"id":2,"exception":["Faraday::ConnectionFailed","Connection refused - connect(2)"]}
2015-07-13T00:48:07.818757+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/journeys_controller.rb:21:in `create'
2015-07-13T00:48:07.818752+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-07-13T00:48:07.818756+00:00 app[web.1]: Faraday::ConnectionFailed (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

what is Faraday? What am I doing wrong here?

Here is my create method for Journey if it will help.

```
def create
        @journey = current_user.journeys.new(journey_params)
        if @journey.save
            redirect_to @journey
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end
```

After playing with it a bit more, it appears that all the CRUD operation returns similar errors. The operation will go through, the the page will display an error.

Comment: What does your `Journey` model class look like? Some code somewhere is trying to use Faraday to connect to perhaps an API. https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=faraday+ruby

Comment: I do have both the searchkick gem and the acts_as_votable gem in my Journey mode. maybe those two are the reasons?

Comment: If I were to put my money on one, it would be searchkick. It looks like it depends on elasticsearch, which depends on faraday. It seems that your app is having trouble connecting to Elasticsearch.